# DoEvents required after .Copy to include entire range?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a procedure which loops through a large number of files on a SharePoint server and consolidates them. I noticed that some of the data was missing, and stepped through the code when that specific file was the current source file.

What I found was that when I used .Copy, it was not copying the entire range of data I had specified. It was stopping at a hidden row where the data was filtered. I noticed that if I stopped the procedure after I had stepped through the copy line, the rest of the data would then be in the copy range as soon as I stopped it. So I tried putting a DoEvents right after the copy line and that seemed to work.

Simplified example:

This code copies B13:BY1270 (the end of the first continuous range before the hidden rows due to a filter)

```
Range("B13:BY" & Range("B1500").End(xlUp).Rows.Row).Copy
```

This code copies B13:BY1270 and B1274:BY1375 (2 separate continuous ranges, excluding the hidden filtered rows)

```
Range("B13:BY" & Range("B1500").End(xlUp).Rows.Row).Copy
DoEvents
```

My question is, what is the logic behind this? Why is the row number from the `Range("B1500").End(xlUp).Rows.Row` being ignored without the `DoEvents`? Why is a pause required for a simple 1 line copy command?

Comment: @roryap: There is no harm in using DoEvents in VBA if used judiciously.

Comment: Mike, `Range("B1500").End(xlUp).Rows.Row` is not being ignored. What actually is happening is that, when you specify `DoEvents`, you are giving enough time for the code to place that range in the clipboard :)

Comment: The code copies the range before the hidden rows, but not after the hidden rows if I exclude `DoEvents`. Is it just that it requires extra processing time to copy when there is more than 1 range involved?

Comment: @royap Terrible advice. Along the lines of 'never use variants'. Pure rubbish.